# WooCommerce REST API with Google UrlFetchApp header authorization not working

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, woocommerce, http-status-code-401, woocommerce-rest-api

**CURRENTLY**

I am utilising WooCommerce REST API in my Google Scripts with the following working code:

```js
    var ck = "ck_longstringlongstringlongstringlongstring";
    var cs = "cs_longstringlongstringlongstringlongstring";
    var website = "https://www.mywebsite.com.au";

    var url = website + "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=" + ck + "&consumer_secret=" + cs; 

    var options =
        {
          "method": "GET",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
          "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        };

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

**PROBLEM**

To improve security, I want to put consumer key and secret into the header, but I cannot get the following script to work

```js
   var url = website + "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders; 

   let authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(ck + ':' + cs);

    var options =
        {
          "method": "GET",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
          "muteHttpExceptions": true,
          "headers": {"Authorization": authHeader},
        };

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Current result = `{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}`

Expected result = JSON of orders

Is it an issue with my code? Or with WooCommerce API or Google Scripts?

Comment: See [mcve]. **Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.**

Comment: @TheMaster, I have added this.

Comment: Try curl -u or postman and confirm that the url and key/secret works properly.

Comment: @TheMaster, I tried a curl command in postman with the result the same as in google script i.e. ```{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}```
Doing some more digging, it seems similar to issue mentioned on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-rest-api-error-401/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

With `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` you need to use `contentType` instead of `Content-Type`.

However, in this case you don't even need to set it since `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default. Same goes for the `method` property; it defaults to `GET`.

Moreover, if you want to err on the side of caution use [`Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(data, charset)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodewebsafedata-charset) to base64 encode your credentials instead of the non-web-safe version.

```js
let url = website + "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"; 
let encoded = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(ck + ':' + cs, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

let options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions":true,
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded
    }
};

let result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: those issues are a coding preference, whether I want to explicitly identify what my request looks like, and I take note of the encoding choice.
However, none of those changes fix the issue.

Comment: Try removing the `muteHttpExceptions` property to see what errors are being reported by the Apps Script Editor. Then you can start trouble-shooting from there on.

Comment: Also how are you handling the `result` variable? Assuming you don't have any other issues going on, you'll need to invoke `JSON.parse()` on it to convert it to an object. See updated script.

Comment: I use JSON.parse() for the result.
But the current result =
`{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}` which would suggest a permission error and that authentication is not working.

Comment: For the string in your `website` variable, does is start with `https://` or `http://`?

Comment: https. I have added to the description.

Comment: Did you switch from using `Content-Type` to `contentType`? Its not a matter of coding preference. The `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` method overrides the `Content-Type` HTTP Header with the value of the `contentType` property.

Comment: I used:
`var url = website + "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?after=" + fromDate + "&per_page=100";  let encoded = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(ck + ':' + cs, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8); let options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions":true,
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded
  };
`
and it returned: `{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}`

Comment: If both curl and GAS are giving you this error, maybe there is something else going on server-side with the Woocommerce API itself.